# How to add polygon layers with the coordinates in azure maps

Tags: angular, azure-maps

I'm using azure maps controls npm package. I've added the code to render the polygon layer.

For some polygons the layer is coming up as expected. For some layer is not coming as expected. For some layer is coming up on zooming.
Following this approach to render the polygon layer.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Polygons/Simple%20MultiPolygon/Simple%20MultiPolygon.html

I'm using azure maps controls npm package. I've added the code to render the polygon layer

Comment: Can you provide more information, perhaps the coordinates of one of the polygons that aren't working. It's likely that the polygon isn't a valid polygon, and that's causing the rendering issue.

Comment: I tried with the same cordinate that are provided in the sample map. In the sample maps it is working fine. But when I try with the same it is not working as expected. "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Polygons/Simple%20MultiPolygon/Simple%20MultiPolygon.html"

Answer (score 1):

That sample adds a single MultiPolygon to the map, not several individual polygons, so if one displays, they all should display. If you are adding additional individual polygons, note that those use a 3D array while MultiPolygons use a 4D array. Verify your polygon is valid GeoJSON here: https://geojson.io/

I'm not able to reproduce the issue you are seeing using the code in the sample. Can you copy/paste the code you are using as there has to be some differences.

Some things to try:

- Try zooming and panning around, perhaps the polygon in question isn't in view.
- Try clearing your browser cache. The Azure Maps sample site is using a preview version of the web SDK (V3) and sometimes there is some conflicts with loaded resources when going back to v2.
- Check the dev tool console for errors.